# Gridview jquery se pierde cuando recargo datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable, gridview

Estoy trabajando con GridView y Jquery en Asp.Net C# para traer los datos de una tabla y que cuando use el datatable me pagine y haga búsqueda sobre los datos

Para ello tengo:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/PaginaPrincipal.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Novedad.aspx.cs" Inherits="Seguimiento_Facturacion.Novedad" ClientIDMode="Static" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <link href="CSS/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    <script src="JS/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <section class="content-header">
                <h1 style ="text-align:center">NOVEDADES</h1>
            </section>

            <section class="content">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 style="text-align:left" class="box-title">INICIATIVA</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="box box-primary">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Identificación Iniciativa</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDNI" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" MaxLength="8"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <%--<asp:Button ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="BUSCAR" />--%>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnBuscarIni" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="BUSCAR" OnClick="btnBuscarIni_Click"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Descripcion</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDescripcion" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Cliente</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNombres" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Cuenta</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCuenta" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="box box-primary">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Piezas</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <%--<asp:Button ID="btn_Nueva_Pieza" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Adicionar Pieza" />--%>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Nueva_Pieza" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" href="#AdicionarPieza" data-toggle="modal">Adicionar Pieza</asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Crear Gread View -->
                <asp:GridView   ID="grdPiezas" runat="server" CssClass =" table table-bordered table-hover" 
                                AutoGenerateColumns ="false" ShowFooter="false" DataKeyNames ="IdPieza">

                    <HeaderStyle BackColor ="#006699" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor ="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor ="White " ForeColor="#000066" />
                    <PagerStyle  BackColor="White"  ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPiezaHeader" runat="server" Text="Pieza"></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPieza" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Descripcion") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLineaNegHeader" runat="server" Text="Linea Neg"></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLineaNeg" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LINEANEG") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCategoriaHeader" runat="server" Text="Categoria"></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCategoria" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CATEGORIA") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEditarHeader" runat="server" Text="Editar"></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%--<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl ="~/Imagenes/edit.ico" runat="server" CommandName ="Editar" />--%>
                                <%--<asp:Label ID="lblCategoria" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CATEGORIA") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Editar_Pieza" CommanArgument ='<%# Eval("IdPieza") %>' CommandName="EditarPieza" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" href="#AdicionarPieza" data-toggle="modal"> <img src="Imagenes/edit.ico"/></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>


                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>


                <asp:GridView ID="grdPiezas_1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass ="display">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField Datafield="Descripcion" HeaderText="Pieza" SortExpression="Pieza"/>
                        <asp:BoundField Datafield="Categoria" HeaderText="Categoria" SortExpression="Categoria"/>

                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>

<%--                <!-- Datatable Part -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="box box-primary">
                            <div class="box-header">
                                <h3 class="box-title">Piezas</h3>
                            </div>


                              <div class ="box-body table-responsive">
                                    <table id="tbl_iniciativas" class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">                            
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <asp:GridView ID="grdPiezas" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass ="display">
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <asp:BoundField Datafield="Descripcion" HeaderText="Pieza" SortExpression="Pieza"/>
                                                        <asp:BoundField Datafield="Categoria" HeaderText="Categoria" SortExpression="Categoria"/>

                                                    </Columns>

                                                </asp:GridView>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <tbody id="tbl_body_table">
                                            <!-- DATA POR MEDIO DE AJAX-->
                                        </tbody>

                                    </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Datatable -->
--%>

            </section>

            <%--Modal para la creacion de Piezas--%>

            <div class="modal fade" id="AdicionarPieza" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <!-- Header de la ventana -->
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                            <h2 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Adicionar Pieza</h2>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Body de la ventana -->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="box box-primary">
                                        <div class="box-body">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Descripción</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescripPieza" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Unidad de Negocio</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddUnidadNeg" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Categoría</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCategoria" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Línea de Negocio</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddLineaNeg" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Unidades</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnidades" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Valor Unitario</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtValorUnit" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="box box-primary">
                                        <div class="box-body">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Requiere Diseño</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbReqDiseno" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" CellPadding = "20" CellSpacing = "20" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns = "2" Width="25%" >
                                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Si</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Requiere Desarrollo</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbReqDesa" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" CellPadding = "20" CellSpacing = "20" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns = "2" Width="25%" >
                                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Si</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>

<%--                                                <div class="radio">
                                                    <label for="NoDesa">No</label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="opReqDesarrollo" id="NoDesa" checked/>
                                                    <label for="SiDesa">Si</label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="opReqDiseño" id="SiDesa" />
                                                </div>--%>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Activo</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbActivo" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" CellPadding = "20" CellSpacing = "20" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns = "2" Width="25%" >
                                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Si</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>

<%--                                                <div class="radio">
                                                    <label for="NoActivo">No</label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="opActivo" id="NoActivo" checked/>
                                                    <label for="SiActivo">Si</label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="opActivo" id="SiActivo" />
                                                </div>--%>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Fecha Estimada Inicio Proyecto:</label>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFecIniProy" CssClass="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'"
                                                        data-mask="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Pie de la Ventana -->
                        <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnGuardarPieza" runat="server" CssClas="btn btn-primary" Text="Guardar" OnClick="btnGuardarPieza_click" OnClientClick="$('#AdicionarPieza').modal('hide');"/>
                            <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>--%>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="footer" runat="server">
    <script src="js/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/Novedades.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</asp:Content>
```

Cuando cargo la primera vez el gridview se muestra bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando hago una búsqueda de un nuevo dato y vuelvo a cargar la tabla se desaparece el formato de paginaciòn, búsqueda y ordenamiento.

Cuando hago la carga utilizo:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('#grdPiezas').DataTable();
});
```

y el aspx

```
private void LlenarGridViewPiezas()
        {

            List<ListaPiezas> ListaPiezasIni = PiezaLN.getInstance().ListarPiezas(12);
            grdPiezas.DataSource = ListaPiezasIni;
            grdPiezas.DataBind();

            grdPiezas.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            grdPiezas.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            grdPiezas.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
}
```

Es decir, cuando vuelvo a ejecutar el codigo de LLenarGridViewPiezas sin recargar la página me aparece así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar ya que llevo bastante tiempo tratando de encontrar una solución a la búsqueda, ordenamiento y paginacion y esta forma es perfecto solo que no me funciona adecuadamente cuando hago una consulta a la base de datos y quiero verla en el gridview.

Answer (score 0):

No tiene ninguna relacion el `Gridview` con el `DataTable`, no aplican juntos. Deberias revisar la documentacion del DataTable:

[DataTable Ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

veras que los datos aplican sobre un `<table>` de `html`

En el ejemplo define

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Para luego asignar los datos que viene  por `ajax`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

No mezcles controles de servidor como son los de `asp.net` con controles de `jquery` es para dolor de cabeza, porque los server control tienen eventos al servidor y requierne un render de la pagina, pero los de ajax no lo necesitan porque las llamadas solo envian los datos y son una llamada ajax asincrona

Comment: Te agradezco mucho tu respuesta.  Pensaba que si podían utilizarse por que en principio funciona bien, el problema está al cargar nuevamente con la consulta que es cuando deja de funcionar.  Como puedo entonces ordenar, buscar y paginar un gridview?.

Comment: funciona porque el gridview seguramente redenderice como table de html por eso el datatable al aplicar lo haga bien, pero despues tienes eventos del gridview que no tienen control el datatable y no deberian aplicar

Comment: el gridview para realizar esas acciones requiere eventos al servidor con lo cual perderas la aplicaicon del datatable, creo que deberias decidir si usar uno u otro, usas el gridview como viene de base o usas datatable

Answer (score 0):

El problema surge al realizar un postback se pierden las propiedades de datatable.

SOLUCIÓN:
Debes volver a invocar la función datatable

En tu función donde realizas la busqueda `OnClick="btnBuscarIni_Click"` al final
ejecuta ScriptManager de la librería System.Web.UI

Ejemplo:

JS

```
function cargardatatable(){
  $('#grdPiezas').DataTable();
}
```

C#

```
protected void btnBuscarIni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  /*TU CODIGO AQUÍ*/
  /*DEBES INCLUIR EN EL ENCABEZADO DE TU ARCHIVO  using System.Web.UI;*/
  /*VUELVE A LLAMAR A LA FUNCION DATATABLE*/
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "cargardatatable();", true);
}
```

ASP.NET

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="Server">
               <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:GridView ID="grdPiezas" runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                     .
                     .
                     .
                    </Columns>
                  </asp:GridView>
               </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```